# steps to package applet with web application to access loca file system

Tags: java, web-applications, applet

I have a requirement to support folder upload using Applet. I have implemented the applet that will try to get a user home directory and will try to create a temp zip file for that folder and then it will hit my upload servlet. Actually creation of zip file and upload would be initiated by calling one of the applet method uploadFolder from JavaScript. While I was creating a zip file in user home directory am getting a java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\Documents and Settings\userhomedir\temp_timestamp.zip write).

**Following are steps I have done:**

**Step 1:**

1. Created a applet to create zip and file hitting a upload servlet along with uploadFolder method.
2. Created a signed jar for that applet project.
3. The html code is

   ```
   <Applet code="com.project.upload.FolderUploadApplet.class" name="uploadApp"
       archive="upload.jar"
       width="250" height="80" >
   </applet>
   ```
4. The JavaScript code is

   ```
   window.alert(uploadApp.uploadFolder(destionationPath));
   ```

**Step 2:**

After this I gone through some forums and decided to go for JWS with JNLP. In step1 I was able to call applet method using JavaScript but When I was doing with JNLP, I was not able to call my applet method through JavaScript. Please find the following code snippet:

**Html**

```
<Applet code="com.altair.cm.upload.FolderUploadApplet.class" id="xyz" archive="scmfu.jar">
    <param name="jnlp_href" value="folderupload.jnlp">  
</applet>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   var app = document.getElementById("xyz");
   window.alert(app.uploadFolder(destionationPath));
```

**folderupload.jnlp**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
        <information>
            <title>Folder Upload</title>
            <vendor>Team</vendor>
        </information>
        <security>
          <all-permissions/>
        </security>
        <resources>
            <!-- Application Resources -->
            <j2se version="1.6+"
                  href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"
                  <!-- secure java vm argument -->
                  java-vm-args="-Xmx1024M"/>
            <jar href="scmfu.jar"
                main="true" />
                <!-- secure properties -->
            <property name="sun.java2d.noddraw"
                value="true"/>
            <property name="jnlp.myProperty"
                value="a user-defined property"/>
        </resources>
        <applet-desc 
             name="uploadApp"
             main-class="com.altair.cm.upload.FolderUploadApplet.class"
             width="600"
             height="200">             
         </applet-desc>
         <update check="background"/>
        </jnlp>
    Applet Code :
    public class FolderUploadApplet extends JApplet {

    public String uploadFolder(String destinationPath){
         String fileName = UploadUtil.getInstance().processZipAndUpload(destinationPath,file.getPath());
         return fileName;
    }
}
```

Can any one suggest me,better way to access to local file system and correct me if am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a trusted applet is called by JS, it would normally become sand-boxed. To get around that, look to wrap the call in a [`PrivilegedAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/PrivilegedAction.html).